# Java 8 Collections Merging List

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying to merge the collections using employee name.

I have a `MainDTO` which has `List<Employee(name, List<Address(String)>)>`

`Employee` has `String name` and `List Address`
`Address` is a `String`.

```
MainDTO -> List<Employee> empList;
Employee-> String name, List<String>
```

I have input data:

```
( ("emp1",[("KY"),"("NY")]),
  ("em2",[("KY"),"("NY")]),
  ("emp1",[("MN"),"("FL")]),
  ("emp1",[("TN"),"("AZ")])
)
```

output will be:

```
( ("emp1",[("KY"),"("NY"),("MN"),"("FL"),("TN"),"("AZ")]),
  ("em2",[("KY"),"("NY")])
)
```

Any best way to sort this data using java 8 or java 7.

Answer (score 5):

If Java 9 was an option, you could use [flatMapping](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<String, List<String>> addressesByEmployeeName = empList
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                Employee::getName, flatMapping(
                        e -> e.getAddresses().stream(),
                        toList())));
```

But I have this weird feeling Java 9 is not an option.

Comment: Nice use of a new JDK 9 feature! +1. It's possible, though more complex, to do this in JDK 8; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35092228/1441122).

Answer (score 2):

[shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35076415/1441122) is nice in that it makes good use of the new JDK 9 `flatMapping` collector. If JDK 9 isn't an option, it's possible to do something similar in JDK 8, although it's a bit more involved. It performs the flat-mapping operation within the stream, resulting in a stream of pairs of employee name and address. Instead of creating a special pair class I'll use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

The basic idea is to stream the list of employees and flat-map them into a stream of pairs of (name, address). Once this is done, collect them into a map, grouping by the name, and collecting the addresses into a list for each group. Here's the code to do that:

```
import static java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import static java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, List<String>> mergedMap =
    empList.stream()
           .flatMap(emp -> emp.getAddresses().stream().map(
                        addr -> new SimpleEntry<>(emp.getName(), addr)))
           .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

This gives a `Map` as a result. If you want to create `Employee` objects from these, you can stream over the entries to create them:

```
List<Employee> mergedEmps =
    mergedMap.entrySet().stream()
             .map(entry -> new Employee(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
             .collect(toList());
```

Creation of map entry objects and extracting data from them is somewhat cumbersome, but not terrible. If you want, some of the idioms here can be extracted into utility methods to make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes much easier if you use a library that has Multimaps such as [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
ListIterable<Employee> empList = ...;
MutableSortedSetMultimap<String, String> addressesByEmployeeName =
    new TreeSortedSetMultimap<>();
empList.each(e -> e.getAddresses().each(a -> addressesByEmployeeName.put(e.getName(), a)));
```

If `empList` and the list of addresses can't be changed from `List` to `ListIterable`, then you can use `ListAdapter` to get this working.

```
ListAdapter.adapt(empList).each(
    e -> ListAdapter.adapt(e.getAddresses()).each(
        a -> addressesByEmployeeName.put(e.getName(), a)));
```

Since this pattern is somewhat common, we may add `RichIterable.toMultimap()` to the library. Then this example would boil down to a one-liner.

```
MutableListMultimap<String, String> addressesByEmployeeName =
    empList.toMultimap(Employee::getName, Employee::getAddresses);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution to your problem - use Set if you want to avoid duplicate values; otherwise, use List:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    final List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> inputData = new ArrayList<>();
    inputData.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, 
            List<String>>("emp1", Arrays.asList("KY","NY")));
    inputData.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, 
            List<String>>("emp2", Arrays.asList("KY","NY")));
    inputData.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, 
            List<String>>("emp1", Arrays.asList("MN","FL")));
    inputData.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, 
            List<String>>("emp1", Arrays.asList("MN","FL")));

    //If you do not care about duplicates - use List
    final Map<String,List<String>> possibleWithDuplicatesData = 
            inputData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    entry -> new ArrayList<String>()));     
    inputData.stream()
    .filter(entry -> possibleWithDuplicatesData.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    .forEach(entry->
    possibleWithDuplicatesData.get(entry.getKey()).addAll(entry.getValue()));

    //If you want to avoid duplicates - use Set
            final Map<String,Set<String>> noDuplicatesData = 
                    inputData.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            entry -> new HashSet<String>()));       
            inputData.stream()
            .filter(entry -> noDuplicatesData.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            .forEach(entry->
            noDuplicatesData.get(entry.getKey()).addAll(entry.getValue()));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static class Address {

    private String address;

    public Address(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
               "address='" + address + '\'' +
               '}';
    }
}

private static class Employee {

    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Employee(String name, List<Address> addresses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
               "name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", addresses=" + addresses +
               '}';
    }
}

private static class MainDTO {

    private List<Employee> employees;

    public MainDTO(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MainDTO{" +
               "employees=" + employees +
               '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee("emp1", Arrays.asList(new Address("KY"), new Address("NY"))));
    employees.add(new Employee("emp2", Arrays.asList(new Address("KY"), new Address("NY"))));
    employees.add(new Employee("emp1", Arrays.asList(new Address("MN"), new Address("FL"))));
    employees.add(new Employee("emp1", Arrays.asList(new Address("TN"), new Address("AZ"))));
    MainDTO dto = new MainDTO(employees);

    List<Employee> merged = dto.getEmployees().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName,
                                  e -> e,
                                  (l, r) ->
                                      new Employee(l.getName(),
                                                        Stream.concat(l.getAddresses().stream(), r.getAddresses().stream())
                                                              .collect(Collectors.toList())),
                                  LinkedHashMap::new))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(merged);
}
```

Couple notes:

- LinkedHashMap is used to preserve original order of list.
- Stream.concat is used in favor of Collection.addAll(Collection) because they could be immutable let's say.

Output:

```
[Employee{name='emp1', addresses=[Address{address='KY'}, Address{address='NY'}, Address{address='MN'}, Address{address='FL'}, Address{address='TN'}, Address{address='AZ'}]}, Employee{name='emp2', addresses=[Address{address='KY'}, Address{address='NY'}]}]
```